# Has anybody (successfully) used Openjpa with Glassfish 4 yet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openjpa, glassfish-4

We're currently using openjpa 2.2.1 with Glassfish 3. Since we have to make changes to our infrastructure anyway, we're considering upgrading to Glassfish 4. Unfortunately, I can't get OpenJpa to work with it. Whenever I try to access a Entity I get AbstractMethodErrors

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;
```

(that is if I enhance the classed during build time with the openjpa-maven-plugin). If I use dynamic enhancement, I can't even deploy the app.

If I switch the persistence provider to EclipseLink, it seems to work fine. Unfortunately changing the persistence provider is not really an option as we use some OpenJPA-Features.

I tried OpenJpa 2.2.2 as well with the same result. On Glassfish 3 the same thing runs just fine.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this since October? I'm having the same error.

Comment: no, we're still stuck. it is as described in the answer below: OpenJPA doesn't yet implement JPA 2.1 which is necessary in GF4. Unfortunately, there seems to be no ETA for JPA 2.1 support in OpenJPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error posted, it looks like Glassfish 4 is assuming the use of a JPA 2.1 provider (due to the use of the SynchronizationType parameter when creating the EM).  OpenJPA does not support the JPA 2.1 specification (yet).

You will need to disable or remove the JPA 2.1 APIs from Glassfish 4 so that the JPA 2.0 APIs can be used (packaged with OpenJPA).  I am not sure how easy or doable this disablement is with Glassfish.

This issue was just created as a JIRA to OpenJPA and referenced this stackoverflow post:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2471